# $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = x -\sqrt{x^2 - x} $

Tags: limits

I have to find the limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = x -\sqrt{x^2 - x} $

= $x(1-(1-\frac{1}{x})^{1/2})$

The part I don't understand is how $ (1 - \frac{1}x)^{1/2}$ = $1 - \frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{8x^2} -...$

Comment: This is due to the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem). Alternatively, we can see that $$x- \sqrt{x^2-x} = \frac {x^2 - (x^2-x)}{x+\sqrt{x^2-x}}$$

Comment: Thanks for that I didn't know.

Comment: Look at the Taylor's series expansion of $f(z)=\sqrt{1-z}$. Here is a helpful Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Answer (score 0):

$(1+y)^{n}= 1+ ny +  \frac{n(n-1)}{2!} y^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!} y^3 + \cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot $

Now , take $y=-\frac{1}{x}$ and $n=\frac{1}{2}$.

Edit : $x-\sqrt{x^{2}-x}$
$=x(1-(1-\frac{1}{x})^{\frac{1}{2}})$
$=x(1-(1-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^2}-\frac{1}{16x^3}-\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot))$
$=\frac{1}{2}+O(\frac{1}{x})$

So, $\lim_{x\to\infty} (x-\sqrt{x^{2}-x}) = \frac{1}{2} $

Comment: This like a taylor serie? I'm not sure why we use that. I mean, if I face this kind of problem I'm pretty sure I'll not have the reflex to use that.

Comment: They just wrote a version of the generalized binomial theorem.

Comment: @proxima : you say in your question , there is a part which you don't understand, that's why I didn't write anything else, as I thought you can do the rest part by yourself!

Comment: I meant, I don't know why we have to do that. I had this answer, but I don't know why.

Comment: @proxima: I edited some.